# Differences between cast and mask

Tags: c

Are there any differences between using the following two approaches to "cut down" the size of a number:

```
int xy=799;

printf("-- %d -- \n", (char) xy);
printf("-- %d -- ", xy & 0xFF);
```

> 31 
> 31

Are there ever any times when one might fail or that one might be better used than other? Note, I'm hoping this isn't an "opinion" question, as I'm a beginner in C I'm actually looking at what the differences between these two approaches are when the mask is of a data-type-sized value.

Comment: One leans on your compiler's overflow handling, the other does the math in a more predictable manner. The result of this depends on if your `char` is signed or not. I'd compile with `-Wall` to see if your `%d` in `printf` can handle a `char`. That should be `%c` or `(int)(char) xy`.

Comment: I really hope that no compiler dares to demote integers without truncating them.

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto: There are reasonable other options to attempts to convert a value to a type in which it is not representable. One is to generate a trap, which is beneficial since it causes bugs to be found earlier. Another is to produce a not-a-number “value.” Another is to clamp. All are useful in various circumstances.

Comment: I think you probably meant `unsigned char`; I would go with whatever conveys the intent of the code more, but that would have been interesting to have a discussion about.

Answer (score 1):

At least this difference.

When `char` is *signed*, `(char) xy` returns values in the [-128...127] range.  If `xy` is outside [-128...127], the result is *implementation defined*.
Some variations when *signed* `char` not 2's complement (rare).
`(char) xy` is [0...255] when `char` is *unsigned*.
Some other variations too if `CHAR_BIT != 8` (rare).

`xy & 0xFF` returns values in the [0...255] range.

---

2nd difference: *type*

The result of `(char) xy` is a `char`.
The result of `xy & 0xFF` is type `int`.

The difference usually does not make a difference in the next step of code, but certainly does with `_Generic`.

---

> Are there ever any times when one might fail or that one might be better used than other?

There is no *fail* case in that *undefined behvior* might occur.

`xy & 0xFF` has the advantage of a single range of possible results under various implementations.

`(char) xy`, when signed, does not change the value when `xy` in the range (-128..127].

Which is better depends on the goals - which are not stated.

Comment: And, of course, this assumes `CHAR_BIT` is 8.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, for now, let us go with the very common `CHAR_BIT == 8` and 2's complement.  IOWs ,`int8_t` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are differences. One selects the 8 least significant bits of a signed integer, and the other converts - depending on whether the implementation considers `char` unsigned or signed, the value to an unsigned byte, or to signed byte with implementation defined behaviour. Notice that if `char` is signed the behaviour specified by the implementation could be anything, such as clamping a value out of bounds instead of taking lowest bits.

What you perhaps intended is the one you did not provide:

```
printf("-- %hhu -- \n", (unsigned char) xy);
```